# Force WordPress to only match URL in category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls

I'm having a problem where if I have the WordPress URL:

```
index.php?post_type=custom_post_type&custom_taxonomy=xyz&custom_post_type=post-slug
```

(Replacing all variables, of course) it will not actually match the custom taxonomy. I can put completely random categories (or nothing at all) and it will match the post with that slug.  How can I force WordPress to *only* look for posts in the related taxonomy?

Comment: You have `post_type` and `custom_post_type`. So far as I know, only `post_type` is valid.

Comment: @s_ha_dum if I have a custom post type "projects" and I load `index.php?projects=post_name`, it will load the correct page, so it must be working.

Comment: oh... that is a placeholder, not a key! You really ought to demarcate those better. If you are feeding the query a post type and a post name, the rest of the query is irrelevant (and will probably be ignored) but I don't have time to dig through into this.

Comment: @s_ha_dum sorry about the confusion.  Ok, that's what I thought - unfortunately in this case it needs to be relevant.  I'll continue looking - thanks

Comment: In what way does it need to be relevant? You are specifying a single post. None of the other data matters if you've singled out a single post. Are you trying to runs a search plus return a single additional post?